# Does saving inside a mongoose pre save hook cause's a loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a forum system API (users, forums, posts) .
My MongoDB Database have a 'categories' collection every category is a wrapper to a group of forums .
Each category have 'order' property which is just a number to help visually sorting categories .
I'm using mongoose module to query the database and i tried to use mongoose pre hook to make sure the order is not messed up(no negative numbers, duplicates, gaps like 0,1, ,3,4).

Basically, each time a new category created run the pre hook which make sure there are no negative numbers no duplicates or gaps and take action accordingly . And i've noticed weird behavior some categories order property was set to numbers that doesn't make sense(i got orders like 1, 2, 4, 7, 8) so this question came up that **maybe i ran into loop but i'm realy not sure since it's not infinite but according to my code and the pre hook if it was a loop it should've been infinite .**

**Main Question :**
Does `mongooseSchema.pre('save'){model.save}` causes a loop?

Related Questions:

1. How do i approach this problem ?
2. In my code i save every category individually inside a foreach loop which seems awful to me is there a way to save them all together? 'bulkwrite' will be kind of the same as saving them individually as far as i know .

Schema + Model:

```
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema<ICategory>({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    order: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
    access: {
        groups: [{ type: Array(mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId), ref: 'Group' }],
        users: [{ type: Array(mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId), ref: 'User' }]
    },
    forums: [{ type: Array(mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId), ref: 'Forum' }]
}, { timestamps: true });

const Category = mongoose.model<ICategory>('Category', categorySchema);
```

Pre hook:

```
// Fixing order in case there is gaps ex: 1,2,3,5 . in case of negative numbers reordering from 0 .
categorySchema.pre('save', async function(){
    const categories: ICategory[] = await Category.find({}).sort({ order: 'asc' });
    if(this.order <= 0){
        this.order = 0;
        let i = 1;
        categories.forEach(category => {
            category.order = i;
            i++;
            category.save();
        });
    }else{
        let i = this.order + 1;
        categories.forEach(category => {
            if(category.order >= this.order){
                category.order = i;
                i++;
                category.save();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I hope it's not a stupid question, i couldn't find an answer and i figure it might be an helpful question. An answer will definitely be helpful for me .

Thanks .

Comment: Shouldn't `category.save();` be with `await`?

Comment: @Anatoly why would it need to be awaited ?

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating-using-save

Comment: @Anatoly Thanks for your response, in this case i am not using the result so i don't really need to wait for it in order to keep executing code . Also it's not the cause of the problem i'm having . Unfortunately i still have no answer for my problem .

Comment: 1. by not waiting for the result you can end up with race condition 2. Is it correct that you save categories inside a hook that trigger on such category saving?

Comment: @Anatoly Hay again, i'm aware of race condition each run of the loop is independent hence it's still doesn't matter as far as i know let me know if i'm wrong(also for the sake of this problem i've tried to await the save and i got the same result). second yes i'm saving a category inside a category pre save hook but as i've written in the question . I'm not sure of if my problem is a loop since if it was it should've been an infinite loop but it's not .

Comment: Ok, can you output  the id and index props of the category right before `save` call to console.log and show the whole output in the post?

Comment: @Anatoly I solved my issue in an answer hopefully it will come handy to other people .

Answer (score 1):

Saving inside a pre save hook does cause a loop .
You can use mongoose `this.isNew` inside the pre hook to check whether it's a new document or updated document this way if you're updating existing documents inside a pre save hook check if they're new or not and just return and it will break to loop .

The reason i didn't got an infinite loop was because i didn't added `next()` to proceed after this middleware .

Updated pre hook :

```
// Fixing order in case there is gaps ex: 1,2,3,5 . in case of negative numbers reordering from 0 .
categorySchema.pre('save', async function(next){
    if(!this.isNew){
        return;
    }
    const categories = await Category.find({}).sort({ order: 'asc' });
    if(this.order <= 0){
        this.order = 0;
        let i = 1;
        categories.forEach(category => {
            console.log(this.id + ' - ' + i);
            category.order = i;
            category.save();
            i++;
        });
    }else{
        let i = this.order + 1;
        categories.forEach(category => {
            if(category.order >= this.order){
                console.log(this.id + ' - ' + i);
                category.order = i;
                category.save();
                i++;
            }
        });
    }
    next();
});
```